# Table looks weird in Firefox, but looks fine on Safari/Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, html-table, width

I'm trying to create a table with a certain layout. The desired output is this (Chrome/Safari):

[image: good result]

However Firefox gives me this:

[image: bad result]

Here is the code for the example:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: white;
}
td {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5">
        <div></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

The only thing I noticed is that the `tr` `width` in Firefox is `326px` while in other browsers it is `310px`. I tried explicitly setting the `width` to `310px` but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display: inline-block` from `td` and add `margin-bottom: -1px` to `div`. [SEE THE DEMO ON FIREFOX](https://jsfiddle.net/037nx022/).

CSS

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
td {
  background-color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: oh that is so stupid for me. I put that to test something and forgot to remove it. Thanks!

Comment: It happens with all ;)